# Using gt functions to style gtsummary merged tables

Tags: gtsummary, gt

I've been utilising the `as_gt()` function to format my `gtsummary` tables and this works fine on each individual table. But when trying to merge tables (`tbl_merge`) together this error appears:

`Error: Error in argument 'x='. Expecting object of class 'gtsummary'`

This happens regardless of feeding the `gt` format options to each individual table, or only to the merged object, same error. Any ideas on workarounds? Repex below.

```r
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(gtsummary)

# Works fine for individual tbls
t1 <-
  glm(response ~ trt + grade + age, trial, family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  as_gt() %>%
      gt::tab_options(table.font.names = "Times New Roman")
t1

t2 <-
  coxph(Surv(ttdeath, death) ~ trt + grade + age, trial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)

# Error appears
tbl_merge_ex1 <-
  tbl_merge(
    tbls = list(t1, t2),
    tab_spanner = c("**Tumor Response**", "**Time to Death**") %>%
      as_gt() %>%
      gt::tab_options(table.font.names = "Times New Roman")
  )

Error: Error in argument 'x='. Expecting object of class 'gtsummary'
```

Comment: put the as_gt() and gt::tab_options after the merge

Comment: `tbl_merge(....)%>%
      as_gt() %>%
      gt::tab_options(table.font.names = "Times New Roman")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove all as_gt() until the very end after the merge like so:

```
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(gtsummary)



t1 <-
  glm(response ~ trt + grade + age, trial, family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) 

t2 <-
  coxph(Surv(ttdeath, death) ~ trt + grade + age, trial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)


tbl_merge_ex1 <-
  tbl_merge(
    tbls = list(t1, t2),
    tab_spanner = c("**Tumor Response**", "**Time to Death**") 
  ) %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gt::tab_options(table.font.names = "Times New Roman")
```